# Seekbar change progress ONLY when dragging Thumb

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I'm facing an issue on how to control Seekbar progress when user **ONLY** touching the **Thumb**

I knew it is a duplicated question but here are the links that gave me an idea about it [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550214/android-seekbar-only-allow-change-with-thumb) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126091/prevent-single-tap-from-changing-seekbar-progress).

After several rounds of testing, below are my working logic result

```
mySeekbar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Rect rcThumb = mySeekbar.getThumb().getBounds();
        int iWidth = rcThumb.width();
        if (event.getX() >= (rcThumb.left - iWidth) && event.getX() <= (rcThumb.right + iWidth)) {
            return false;
        } else
            return true;
    }
});
```

**Expected result**
no drag or tap 
 
 [image: when released]
during drag or tap 
 
[image] 
**Problem**
You can just copy and paste the above code for testing. As we know that when touching or dragging the thumb will be larger, but there is an issue were thumb will be large when not touching it. This issue will not happen often but seldom. Anyway to solve this ? Much help is appreciated.

**Problem result**
no drag or tap 
 
 [image: when released]
during drag or tap 
 
[image]

Comment: are there anyone who can assist with this issue? or my question is confusing?

Comment: Problem resolved. Kindly refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38823873/7094146) to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After few rounds of testing, I was able to accomplish the result. Cheers :)

```
  private boolean mIsDragging;

  private boolean isWithinThumb(MotionEvent event, SeekBar seekBar) {
    Rect rcThumb = seekBar.getThumb().getBounds();
    Rect rcDetectTouchArea = new Rect();
    int iWidth = rcThumb.width();
    int iHeight = rcThumb.height();
    rcDetectTouchArea.left = rcThumb.left - iWidth;
    rcDetectTouchArea.right = rcThumb.right + iWidth;
    rcDetectTouchArea.bottom = rcThumb.bottom + iHeight;
    Log.i("TAG", "rcDetectSize.left  = " + rcDetectTouchArea.left + " | rcDetectSize.right = " + rcDetectTouchArea.right + " |  rcDetectSize.bottom = " + rcDetectTouchArea.bottom + " | event.getX()= " + event.getX() + " | event.getY()= " + event.getY() + " | rcThumb  area = " + rcDetectTouchArea.contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY()));
    return rcDetectTouchArea.contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
}

  mSbTest.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        if (isWithinThumb(event, mSbTest)) {
                            mIsDragging = true;
                            return false;
                        }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (mIsDragging) {
                            mIsDragging = false;
                            return false;
                        }
                        if (isWithinThumb(event, mSbTest)) {
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            return true;
                        }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (!mIsDragging) {
                            return true;
                        }
                }
                return onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });
```